# listview with array in android

Tags: android, listview

Hi In My Application I am using list view in that i used 3 lists named as History", "Our Vision", "Our Branches" now if i click on the history link i want to open the html page.before i used only one class it was open html files correctly after i added one more class in our school.java file then problem occurs.Now my problem is if i click the history page i want to open html file and if i click the our branches it will open another list what i gave in array

OurSchool.java:

```
public class OurSchool extends ListActivity{

 String[] listItems={"History", "Our Vision", "Our Branches"};
 boolean[] listImages= {true, true, true};


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.our_school);
        setListAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, R.layout.our_school, R.id.text1, R.id.image1, listItems, listImages ));
        this.getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    final int pos, long id) {
                Intent i1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), History.class);
                // sending data to new activity
                i1.putExtra("pos", pos);
                startActivity(i1);
            }
        });
this.getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    final int pos, long id) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OurBranches.class);
                // sending data to new activity
                i.putExtra("pos", pos);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
    }
```

History.java:
    public class History extends Activity {

```
    WebView mWebView;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.history);   

        int pos = getIntent().getIntExtra("pos",0);      

        mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.setBackgroundColor(0);
        mWebView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg);
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        switch (pos) {
        case 0:
            mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/History.html");
            break;
        case 1:
            mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Mission And Objectives.html");
            break;

        case 2:
            /*Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OurBranches.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;*/
        default:
            mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/History.html");
            break;
        }


    }

      }
```

history.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="About :Vivero International Pre-School"
        android:textColor="#0000FF"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />


</LinearLayout>
```

our_school.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/layercontainer"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="#ffffff">
   <ListView
   android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor="#008000" 
    android:typeface="sans"/>

   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

before i used only one class it was open html files correctly after i added one more class in our school.java file then problem occurs.Now my problem is if i click the history page i want to open html file and if i click the our branches it will open another list what i gave in array

Thank you,

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: hi i am not getting error if i click history i want to open the html page but now redirecting to branches page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you override the first OnItemClickListener with the second, you have to do something like that:

```
public class OurSchool extends ListActivity{

String[] listItems={"History", "Our Vision", "Our Branches"};
boolean[] listImages= {true, true, true};


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.our_school);
    setListAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, R.layout.our_school, R.id.text1, R.id.image1, listItems, listImages ));

    this.getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int pos, long id) {

            Intent i;

            switch(pos)
            {
                default:
                case 0:
                    i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), History.class);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OurVision.class); // I assumed that this is the class name.
                    break;
                case 2:
                    i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OurBranches.class);
                    break;
            }

            // sending data to new activity
            i.putExtra("pos", pos);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
}
```

So you just need to put one OnItemClickListener and implement inside a switch to create the different Intents for every Activity:

```
    this.getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int pos, long id) {

            Intent i;

            switch(pos)
            {
                default:
                case 0:
                    i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), History.class);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OurVision.class); // I assumed that this is the class name.
                    break;
                case 2:
                    i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OurBranches.class);
                    break;
            }

            // sending data to new activity
            i.putExtra("pos", pos);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Comment: hi can you please tell me what i have to change

Comment: I added more info in the answer, please mark the answer as correct if it solved your problem :)